# How to prevent swiping by dragging in idangero swiper?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, idangero

I need to prevent swiping by dragging (mouse, fingers), but keep it when using pagination buttons and next or prev button.

Here is how I initialize it:

```
var pcSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container_pc', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 20,
        nested: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out `disableTouchControl` method also disables mouse dragging (not only touch dragging). So, the name and description of this method are a little bit unclear, but it works.

```
pcSwiper.disableTouchControl();
```